# Is there any Free chart Control Library for IOS app charts like Pie, Bar, Line, Area

Tags: ios

Is there any Free chart Control Library for IOS app charts like Pie, Bar, Line, Area chart if there pls can you provide me on stack overflow ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 5):

1. [Core Plot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)
2. [blog.oofn](http://blog.oofn.net/projects/)
3. [sm2dgraphview](http://developer.snowmintcs.com/frameworks/sm2dgraphview/index.html)
4. [ivisualization](http://www.ivisualization.com/)
5. [iphone.orp](http://iphone.orpi.pl/?p=20)
6. [powerplot](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/)
7. [RPRadarChart](https://github.com/raspu/RPRadarChart)
8. [keepedge](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)
9. [iOSPlot](https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot)
10. [FRD3DBarChart](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/frd3dbarchart)
11. [GraphView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/graphview)
12. [F3Plotstrip](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/f3plotstrip)
13. [Percentage Chart](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/percentagechart)
14. [Tapku Graph](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapku-graph)
15. [Sparklines](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sparklines)
16. [ADGraphview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/adgraphview)
17. [PNChart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart)
18. [VBPieChart](https://github.com/sakrist/VBPieChart)

Among these Core Plot is more stable (Personal Opinion)

Comment: Try https://cocoapods.org/pods/charts

Answer (score 3):

How about try [PNChart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart)
It supports LineChart, BarChart And Circle Chart

Answer (score 2):

You can check this library https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/
It is under BSD license.